# Horizontal Stack View New Row - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, stack, subview

Stack Views's in iOS are a beautiful thing but I have realized there is no native way to create new rows in horizontal stack views. Let's say I dynamically added subviews in a horiztonal stack view and would want to create a new row once I reach an increment of 3 subviews respectively.

[image: subview array stacked horizontally and vertically]

**Would I be required to create a vertical stack view then programmatically populate it with *individual* horizontal stack views at an interval of 3 increments?**

If so, would swift support dynamic variable creation of horzStackView1, horzStackView2, ... ?

I'm starting to believe there is an easier way to implement this but I can't think of anything as I'm new to Swift 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you would have to manually setup the the vertical and horizontal stack views yourself.

You may want to look into using `UICollectionView` it supports having cells automatically wrap onto the next row if there is not enough space.